# Decoding a device payload sent to the Helium Console

Tags: javascript, iot, lorawan

So I have defined an integration in the Helium Console (i.e. - an IoT LoRaWAN networking service). When I test out sending data from my IoT device to my Helium Console integration endpoint, I can see the payload. And I can manually decode it back to the JSON request body that's correct. But am having trouble defining a custom function in the Helium Console that will automate this for the integration. My IoT device is serializing a MsgPack payload of environmental data that's then sent to the Helium Console integration endpoint. And the Helium Console custom function allows Javascript, although just bare-bones without any requires, imports, etc.

Below is the Python script that can manually decode the payload. If anyone is familiar with this area I'd be interested as to suggestions. There are pre-defined decoders available for Helium, although none that match exactly my hardware.

If anyone has created custom decoding functions for Helium Console integrations I'd be curious as to how I could knock this out. Here is some info about this --> https://docs.helium.com/use-the-network/console/functions/.

```
import ssl, sys, json, base64
import msgpack

payload = "haJiVspAozMzo3RfQxilZWNfbVMWonBoB6NvcnAC"

# decode the payload from base64 and unpack
b64 = base64.b64decode(payload)
mp_dict = msgpack.unpackb(b64)

print(mp_dict) # output is {'bV': 5.099999904632568, 't_C': 24, 'orp': 2, 'ph': 7, 'ec_mS': 22}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I modified the Arduino code running on my device. Pulling in the CayenneLPP library I manually encode what I need, so that the Helium Console's canned CayenneLPP decoding function can correctly parse the data.

Arduino code snippet below.

```
#include <CayenneLPP.h>
...

/*CayenneLPP variable*/
CayenneLPP lpp(51);

...

static void prepareTxFrame( uint8_t port )
{
    appDataSize = lpp.getSize();
    uint8_t lppBuffer[128];
    memcpy(lppBuffer, lpp.getBuffer(), 128); 
    memcpy(appData, lppBuffer, lpp.getSize());    
}

...

// The loop function is called in an endless loop
void loop()
{
    lpp.reset();
    lpp.addTemperature(1, 22.5);
    lpp.addBarometricPressure(2, 1073.21);
    lpp.addGPS(3, 52.37365, 4.88650, 2);

    ...

    LoRaWAN.displaySending();
    prepareTxFrame( appPort );
    LoRaWAN.send(loraWanClass);

    ...
 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/helium/console-decoders/blob/master/debugDecodeBase64.js

```
// LoRaWan devices automatically base64 encode data sent
// Sometimes nice just to view what original payload was sent
//
// This can help when writing your own decoder
//
//

 function Decoder(bytes, port, uplink_info) {
  var decoded={};
  try{
  var result = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes);
  decoded.value = result;
  return decoded;
  } catch (err) {
  return 'Decoder: ' + err.name + " : " + err.message;;
  }
 }

// And in the integration section of the Helium console use this JSON
// For an Adafruit.io integration which is expecting JSON like { "value" : "56" }
//
// { "value": {{decoded.payload.value}} }
```

1. Create account on https://app.datacake.de/
2. Create integration to Datacake in here: https://console.helium.com/integrations
   [integrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YggDA.png)
3. Link the flow in here:
   https://console.helium.com/flows
   [flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz34B.png)
4. Create project and add device to DataCake, as decoder function use modified above (as is - it will receive a string)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.